# Multiple files download in WP8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am developing an app which holds multiple files to download, but I am getting single file at a time.

Code which I implemented on button click to download file is below:

```
private async void ButtonDownload_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    string uri = "download url****************************";
    StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    if (folder != null)
    {
        StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(++fileNo + "stVideo.mp4", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
        downloadOperation = backgroundDownloader.CreateDownload(new Uri(uri), file);
        Progress<DownloadOperation> progress = new Progress<DownloadOperation>(progressChanged);
        cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

        try
        {
            TextBlockStatus.Text = "Initializing...";
            await downloadOperation.StartAsync().AsTask(cancellationToken.Token, progress);
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException)
        {
            TextBlockStatus.Text = "Download canceled.";
            downloadOperation.ResultFile.DeleteAsync().AsTask().Wait();

            ButtonDownload.IsEnabled = true;
            downloadOperation = null;
        }
    }
}
```

**and progress changed event is following:**

```
private void progressChanged(DownloadOperation downloadOperation)
{
    int progress = (int)(100 * ((double)downloadOperation.Progress.BytesReceived / (double)downloadOperation.Progress.TotalBytesToReceive));
    TextBlockProgress.Text = String.Format("{0} of {1} kb. downloaded - %{2} complete.", downloadOperation.Progress.BytesReceived / 1024, downloadOperation.Progress.TotalBytesToReceive / 1024, progress);
    ProgressBarDownload.Value = progress;
    switch (downloadOperation.Progress.Status)
    {
        case BackgroundTransferStatus.Running:
        {
            TextBlockStatus.Text = "Downloading...";
            break;
        }
        case BackgroundTransferStatus.Completed:
        {
            TextBlockStatus.Text = "Download complete.";
            downloadOperation = null;
            break;
        }
        case BackgroundTransferStatus.PausedByApplication:
        {
            TextBlockStatus.Text = "Download paused.";
            break;
        }
        case BackgroundTransferStatus.PausedCostedNetwork:
        {
            TextBlockStatus.Text = "Download paused because of metered connection.";
            break;
        }
        case BackgroundTransferStatus.PausedNoNetwork:
        {
            TextBlockStatus.Text = "No network detected. Please check your internet connection.";
            break;
        }
        case BackgroundTransferStatus.Error:
        {
            TextBlockStatus.Text = "An error occured while downloading.";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

But I am unable to come up with a solution to download multiple files.

Please elaborate to me how to get rid out from this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you clicked twice or more - you create a multiple downloads with one progress handler.
When you created a download operation item system generates unique id - Guid.
You can determine which item downloads in **progressChanged**

As I know:

1. Maximum download operations in the same moment - 5
2. Maximum download operations in queue - 500

### UPDATE:

I created simple sample for background downloading. You can download sample from [OneDrive](http://1drv.ms/1DgpACh)

Comment: Thanks for that can you please provide me some code snippets for which i can start to work for multiple downloading